# How to show that for $a_n := \left( \frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n} \right)$, $a_n \rightarrow 4/e$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I'm asked [in a homework problem set] to show that for $a_n := \left( \frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n} \right)$, $a_n \rightarrow 4/e$.  I'm told to show that this function is Riemann integrable for $ln(a_n)$.  I have a fairly good idea on how to do this [the 2nd idea is probably better]:

**1st Idea:**

$U(ln(a_n), P)-L(ln(a_n),P) =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} ln\left(\frac{n+j}{n+j-1}\right) \Delta x_j$ [through some work], for some arbitrary partition $P$.

I'm having $2$ problems:

($1$)  How do I form the partition $P$ sucht hat $U-L< \epsilon$?  [if im not mistaken, then if each $\Delta x_j=1$, then $U-P=\frac{ln(2)}{n}$].

($2$)  How does this help me find the limit of $a_n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

**2nd Idea:**

The hint the book gives is to use Riemann sums by taking the natural log of $a_n$.  I feel as though this problem will boil down to proving

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left[\ln(\frac{n+1}{n^n})+\ln(\frac{n+2}{n^n})+...+\ln(\frac{n+n}{n^n})\right]=\ln(4)-\ln(e)=\ln(4)-1$.

Showing this [using Riemann sums/integration as my guess] would give that  $\ln(a_n) \rightarrow \ln(4/e) \implies a_n \rightarrow 4/e$.
I appreciate any hints!

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this helps... the only mention of a limit in Sterlin's approximation doesn't appear to have any relevance here.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lucian I've edited the main question with the '2nd idea.'  Maybe this seems like a correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log a_n = \log \frac{(2n)!}{n! n^n} = \log \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{n+k}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left( 1 + \frac{k}{n} \right).$$  Therefore, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log a_n}{n} = \int_{x=0}^1 \log (1+x) \, dx,$$ and it would follow that $a_n \sim (4/e)^n$, but $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Indeed...hmmm...let's see where I went wrong  @_@

Comment: Wouldn't $\ln\left(\frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n} \right)=\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{n+k}{n^n}\right)$?  How is that the same sum as $\sum_{k=1}^n \log \left( 1 + \frac{k}{n} \right)$?

Comment: Nope:  write $$(2n)!/(n! n^n) = (n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+n)/(n\cdot n \ldots n) = (1+1/n)(1+2/n)\cdots(1+n/n).$$

Comment: I see!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

in your question, there should be nth root of whole a_n.Then apply ratio and root test equality theorem,you will get correct answer.